# Get Distinct values for each column without re-executing the same query

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to return unique values based on a query in MySQL without re-executing the same query for each column?

I have a somewhat complex query which includes a few joins and could return 50,000+ rows.  My goal is get all the unique values of each column as if I had done:

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_a FROM ...
```

For each column.  Is there any way to get this done without running the query many times?

Comment: Mysql internally caches the queries so subsequent queries will be faster. But I think you want another level caching? Memcache? Then you're risking running into stale data if you're not running your full query again

Comment: good point about the caching.  do you think would it be faster or slower to actually build a temp table based on initial results?

Comment: it all depends on your data, your indexes, the amount of ram you've allocated to the process, and how many other queries get executed in between your queries

Answer (score 0):

you can use column subquery. example

```
  mysql> select (select name from city order by rand() limit 1) "randdom value1", (select name from city order by rand() limit 1) "random value2", name "actual value" from city limit 10;

+--------------------+-------------------+----------------+
| randdom value1     | random value2     | actual value   |
+--------------------+-------------------+----------------+
| Valle de Santiago  | Shulin            | Kabul          |
| Ibarra             | Xiangfan          | Qandahar       |
| Kingston upon Hull | Bataisk           | Herat          |
| Huancayo           | Fort Worth        | Mazar-e-Sharif |
| Longyan            | Linköping         | Amsterdam      |
| Cheju              | Rubtsovsk         | Rotterdam      |
| Aligarh            | Bergisch Gladbach | Haag           |
| Najran             | Pultava [Poltava] | Utrecht        |
| Shuangyashan       | Cedar Rapids      | Eindhoven      |
| Buffalo            | Abilene           | Tilburg        |
+--------------------+-------------------+----------------+
10 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```